# how to change a char field to list field or array field in Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want the Char field "device_id" to be changed to a list field or an array field without loosing the current data present in the field , so it can hold  multiple device ids.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email address", max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

Usecase :I need the user to be associated with multiple devices here after

Comment: You need to make a [Data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: I guess you need `ManyToMany` relationships. If so, I suggest you to create a new field `devices = ManyToManyField(User)` and do necessary migrations. Then write a simple script to create relations based on `device_id` field. After completing, delete the `device_id` field.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz yes that's what I need , but how to get the values from the old field to the new one ?, I am newbie here , could you please help me in this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a model for Device like so:

```
class Device(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then you can add a new field to User model (Do not remove old one yet).

```
device_ids = models.ManyToManyField(YouDeviceModel)
```

migrate database

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate
```

Then add current files inside one of your apps (only temporary)

```
management\
   __init__.py
   commands\
      __init__.py
      migrateuser.py
```

inside `migrateuser.py`:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from yourapp.models import Device #your device model

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.all()

        for user in users:
            device = Device.objects.create(name=user.device_id)
            user.device_ids.add(device)
```

in shell run `py manage.py migrateuser`.

Remove field `device_id` and run migrations again.

Comment: Instead of a management command it would be better for this to be a [Data Migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: Yes, that's probably better. This will work fine if it's just a one-off though and you have no production database yet. But you're right, a Data Migration is a better practice.

Comment: getting this error "Unknown command: 'migrateuser'. Did you mean migrate?" while running py manage.py migrateuser.

Comment: It should be `migrateuser`. It's the custom command we created. Did you create the files `management/commands/migrateuser.py` with `__init__.py` files inside each folder. This should be placed inside an app. Not directly in project.

Comment: @FelixEklöf you haven't shown properly the way to make a management command. You need a `Command` class which subclasses `BaseCommand` in the file. Reference https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/ ...

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Command class. I made an edit. Code inside `migrateuser.py` is changed.

Comment: Thank so much to both FelixEklöf and @AbdulAzizBarkat Aziz